# Is there any advantage in using rosfmt instead of ros stream print function?

Tags: c++, ros

I've seen the ROS wrapper for `fmt` library, called [rosfmt](https://github.com/xqms/rosfmt), and was wondering if the performance is somehow better than using the `ROS_WARN_STREAM(...)` or similar functions

Comment: And btw. I just learnt (on the [fmt github site](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)) that the performance of fmt beats the printf family and C++ stream output significantly. rosfmt probably benefits from this but if in doubt you may profile by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer to your question is what only direct profiling on the same system can give. In fact, it is expected that `libfmt` would beat `printf` system call because it implements complex output treatment, actually, a programming language, like `awk` does. As can be observable from the code, `libfmt` hardcodes many routines, so it **can be** faster than STL streams, but it depends totally on the current implementation. For ROS, avoidance of `printf`-based routines is definitely an advantage.